# How can I control position of scroll in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i need when scroll to top position or first item show in the recyclerview do something like show toolbar and when scroll down or hide first item in recyclerview hide toolbar or do somethinghing

Answer (score 0):

You can try
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu7Fw.png)

Comment: Please avoid answering in form of image.Image text does not come up on search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  contenuRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() != 1){
                // visible toolbar
            } else {
                // gone toolbar
            }

        }
    });
```

yourLayoutManager can be :

- LinearLayoutManger
- GridLayoutManager
- StaggeredGridLayoutManager